# replace multiple whitespace with single space but keep new lines in regex match (python)

Tags: python

How can I clean up the following text with regex in python? I'm trying to replace multiple whitespaces and tabs with single spaces, but preserve new lines.

`test = "This      is a    test. \n  Blah     blah."`

In my new string, I want it to be:

`"This is a test. \n Blah blah."`

I've tried the following expression in an attempt to ignore new line characters, but it doesn't seem to work.

`result = re.sub('[^\n]\s\s+', ' ', test)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code below:

```py
import re
test = "This      is a    test. \n  Blah     blah."
print(re.sub(r"(?:(?!\n)\s)+", " ",test))
```

##### Output

```
This is a test. 
 Blah blah.
```